# Создание сложной кнопки

Tags: android

В приложении от Юлмарт на карточке товара присутствует вот такая красивая кнопка:
[image: сложная кнопка]
Хочу создать такую же, но элемент Button позволяет создать название кнопки с иконкой. Не подходит.

Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разметка кнопки:

```
<LinearLayout android:width="match_parent" android:height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <TextView android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content"  android:text="860dp" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_ruble" android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>

    <Space android:width="0dp" android:weight="1">

    <TextView android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content"  android:text="860dp" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cart" android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`bg.xml` в `res/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Останется только добавить иконки `ic_cart` и `ic_ruble`

Фон можно улучшить, используя `selector`, который позволит показывать разные состояния, путём смены цвета.